# Passing Array from one class to another

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsarray

I am trying to pass Array from one class to another I used

```
detailViewController.nameArray = [feed valueForKey:@"id"];
```

This is working fine..when I used like

```
detailViewController.nameArray=[[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data" ]valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

It is throwing exception ....
while pass this into string is fine

```
NSString *commentId = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data" ]valueForKey:@"id"]];
```

use like

```
detailViewController.commentId= commentId ;
```

In next class

```
Cell.textLabel.text = commentId;
```

This is showing all the comments in one cell. I have to show one comment in one cell.. How can I do this?

Comment: What exception is the second piece of code throwing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs at:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Claim that comments is a:

> Structure containing a data object containing an array of objects, each with the id, from, message, and created_time for each comment

In which case `[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data"]` should return an NSArray, in which you'll find the comment objects themselves, with their IDs.

Comment: Yes It is returning string... Can you tell me how can I parse this?

Comment: Which bit is returning a string? What's the actual data structure? As I say, 'comments' makes it sound like that's an array.

Comment: NSString *commentId = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[feed valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"data" ]valueForKey:@"id"]];
NSLog(@"Comment Id is %@:",commentId); is showing output

Comment: (
    "100001507678574_173436826049905_1826918",
        "100001507678574_173436826049905_1826933"
    ),

Comment: have you seen facebook graph api?